# CKEditor 4 not showing all toolbar properties

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4-react) for a React project. I've installed it via `yarn add ckeditor4-react`. However, I've noticed that there are some properties in the toolbar that are missing (table properties for example).

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I know that there are instructions to add extra plugins in CKEditor, however, I've tried to replicate the same behavior on my project in a code sandbox. In doing so, I can see all the properties that I would expect in the code sandbox, simply by adding `ckeditor4-react` as a dependency, and without adding any additional plugins. The example, **which works fine**, is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-shannon-x9so0s?file=/src/App.js

This is what the toolbar looks like in the above example:

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot more properties in the toolbar from my code sandbox example than in my actual project. I'm trying to add a table to the `initData` and it works on the code sandbox example but not my project. I can assume that it's because of the missing properties. In essence, I'm trying to render a simple table. But when I inspect the element using the dev tools, I can see that the `table` tags have been replaced by `p` tags. The only difference between both is that I'm using `yarn` in my project where as `ckeditor4-react` is installed using `npm` on code sandbox.

I know it might be hard to understand the problem, but is there any reason why a simple `yarn add ckeditor4-react` wouldn't add all the toolbar properties? I've even added the extra properties in the toolbar group within the `config`.

The way I'm using the component in my project looks like the following. I'm most interested in showing the table properties at this moment, which is why I've added `config={{ toolbar: [{ name: 'insert', items: ['Table'] }] }}`

```
import { CKEditor } from 'ckeditor4-react';

<CKEditor
    config={{
      toolbar: [{ name: 'insert', items: ['Table'] }]
    }}
    initData={`<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    `}
    data-testid="ckeditor-textfield"
/>
```